# Calling XML-RPC service from .NET without extra libraries

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, xml-rpc

I have simple XML-RPC server written in PHP. It handles 1 table in database, it has 3 methods: addRow, deleteRow, getAllRows.

I want to call these methods from my .NET desktop application.

Do I have to use extra libraries (like xml-rpc.net), or there is some simple alternative built in .NET?

Comment: You can send XML over HTTP by using LINQ to XML and WebClient (or HttpClient if you're modern).

Comment: Some code example would be very useful. I can't find any by googling "HttpClient .net xmlrpc".

Comment: That's because you shouldn't need any code example. Do you know the XML-RPC protocol? Then use LINQ to XML to create the XML you want to send. HttpClient and WebClient are just about sending stuff over HTTP. So once you have the XML to send, just send it.

Comment: I have only fragmentary knowledge about XML-RPC. I was using IXR and phpxmlrpc libraries, but I don't know what these libraries do. Looks like I have to read more about this.